# Hierarchical Component not sending emit in Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, components

Hi I am trying to implement a treeview. I have a component for it which is hierarchical. The problem I am facing is that emit is not working inside tree component. Please help me out. here is my code...

**TreeItem.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="node" :style="{ marginLeft: depth * 20 + 'px' }">
    <span class="menu-item" v-if="type == 'country'">
            <button class="menu-button menu-button--orange" @click="addState()">
              Add State
            </button>
          </span>
<TreeItem
      v-if="expanded"
      v-for="child in node.children"
      :key="child.name"
      :node="child"
      :depth="depth + 1"
    />
</div></template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TreeItem",
  props: {
    node: Object,
    depth: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    emits: ["add-state"],
  },
  data() {
    return {
      expanded: false,
    };
  },
methods: {
 addState() {
      console.log("Adding State"); //Prints this message to console
      this.$emit("add-state");
    },

},
};

</script>
```

**AddressManager.vue**

Inside template:

```
 <div>
          <tree-item :node="treedata" @add-state="addState"></tree-item>
        </div>
```

Inside Methods:

```
addState() {
      console.log("State will be added"); //Never prints this message
    },
```

We need to emit on button click. But the emit is not working.

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out the problem... We need to replace `this.$emit()` with `this.$parent.$emit()`

Here is the change-

```
addState() {
      console.log("Adding State"); //Prints this message to console
      this.$parent.$emit("add-state");
    },
```

Hopefully this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use v-on="$listeners" to pass emits on levels above within the depths https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components it would just forward them to the parent.

However in nested scenarios it is more convenient using store (vuex) and assign a property then watch property changes from wherever you would like to notice its change. If you use vuex: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch store properties can be watched.